# Exception has occurred. RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

Tags: image, google-maps, flutter

[Am I getting something wrong here please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD493.png)

```
 //To convert
    final decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    //print(decodedResponse);

    final formattedAddress = decodedResponse['results'](**I KEEP GETTING THE ERROR HERE**)[0]['formatted_address'];
    final coords = decodedResponse['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
```